# Vb.Net Control Variable Names

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am trying to create bunch of WebBrowsers with Variable Names; I started with the following code, but seems it has something wrong that I cannot figure our;
The error is in the FIRST PORTION OF THE CODE;

Any help/comment appreciated:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumberOfBrowsers As Integer = 12
    For Pro As Integer = 1 To NumberOfBrowsers
        Dim frmNew As New Form
        '------------------------- FIRST PORTION:
        Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser
        MekdamBrowser = "WebBrowser" & Pro
        frmNew.Controls.Add(MekdamBrowser)
        '-------------------------
        MekdamBrowser.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
        MekdamBrowser.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(300, 300)
        MekdamBrowser.Show()
        '-------------------------
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is 'MekdamBrowser' an array?

Comment: Also, are you intending to create a number of 'Forms' equal to the number of WebBrowsers?

Comment: It doesn't have to be array; I was just experimenting and this was the last version. I was not successful in solving this. The answer to number of forms, is again it is part of my experiment. The question is: Is it possible to have variable webbrowser name???

Comment: Then why is it an array?

Comment: I am sorry; I removed the array; do you know how to have variable webbrowser name???

Comment: do you mean this: `MekdamBrowser.Name = "WebBrowser" & Pro` ?

Comment: Thanks har07; you are great; I missed the ".Name"; I think I cannot accept your answer in the comment?? I will accept it is you post it as answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the first portion to be as follow instead :

```
'------------------------- FIRST PORTION:
Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser
MekdamBrowser.Name = "WebBrowser" & Pro
frmNew.Controls.Add(MekdamBrowser)
'-------------------------
```

The difference between this and the original code you tried is, above code assigns name for `WebBrowser` control, where corresponding line of code in question tried to "replace" `WebBrowser` control it self with a name (it tried to assign string data to variable of type `WebBrowser` which is not a valid operation).